# Retrieve data from store using ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

How can I retrieve observable data from a NgRx store?

```
this.users$ = this.store.select(getAllUsers);
console.log('res',this.users$);
```

Using the above code snippet, I got the expected result:

```
{store: {actionsObserver: {_value:{user:[{}, {}, {} ... ,{} ]}}}}
```

At that time, I have tried this code:

```
this.store.select(getAllUsers).subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log('data',data)
});
```

Using the above subscribe method, I am getting only first row of user array, but I am expecting the whole user array as result.

Would you please tell me the correct code to read data in _value ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is in your getAllUsers slector. Please share the definition of the selector.

Comment: @Manox
import { UserState } from './user.reducers';
import { UserModel } from '.././user.model';

import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectAll, selectIds } from './user.reducers';


export const userFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<UserState>('users');

export const getAllUsers = createSelector(
  userFeatureSelector,
  selectAll
);

export const areUsersLoaded = createSelector(

  userFeatureSelector,
  state => state.usersLoaded
);

Comment: I am sorry, but there is too little information, to really help you. Please edit your question and share your reducers, selectors, state, model and other involved code parts.